# What is theme-compat?

Tags: themes

I have noticed that `wp-includes/theme-compat` directory.
So, what is it?
Is it a theme?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `theme-compat` directory is comprised of a set of **deprecated** (since WordPress 3.0) files that WordPress *used* to use as fallback template-part files, in case the active Theme failed to include them.

In other words, if a Theme used the `get_header()` template tag, but failed to include a `header.php` template-part file, WordPress would fall back to `/wp-includes/theme-compat/header.php`.

The template-part files in `theme_compat` are **deprecated**, unmaintained, incredibly old (by core/current-Theme standards), and should not be relied upon by any current Theme.