# Wordpress error when sending comment

Tags: comments

I'm using the default comments template. When I send a comment I get the following error message:

**Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_set_comment_cookies' not found or invalid function name in /home/mattator/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 403**

**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mattator/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:403) in /home/mattator/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 881**

couldn't find a call to the funciton 'wp_set_comment_cookies' anywhere in the code.
It is noteworthy that despite the error message the comment is being sent properly.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What **Theme** are you using? What **Plugins are active**?

Comment: I'm using my own self-built theme. I am using the native WP comments template. Turned off all plugins and the problem still persists.

Comment: What "*native WP comments template*" are you using?

Comment: I'm using the "comments_template()" function with no additional parameters, which loads the default "comments.php" from the wp-includes library. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I experimented a little bit, and as turns out the problem was a call to the function "nocache_headers()", in Line 18 of the file "wp-comments-post.php" which lies at WP root directory.
I deleted it, and voila, everything works. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using the "comments_template()" function with no additional parameters, which loads the default "comments.php" from the wp-includes library.

That's your problem.

The compat version is unmaintained and obsolete. Theme-compat files are officially no longer supported, as of WordPress 3.0. ([See here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54504/3966).)

You need to define and include `comments.php` in your Theme.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that I have to create the whole comment system from scratch, or is there a more up-to-date file I can refer to?

Comment: I tried the twentyeleven comments template and got the same error

Comment: Exactly the same error? Can we see relevant code? Your `comments.php`, relevant parts of `functions.php`, and template file(s) where you call `comments_template()`?